# I need help deleting an instantiated object after another one has created - unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a script where I ray cast the mouse pointer position and create an object there. I've gotten to that but I want to make it after you create a new instantiated object the one before gets deleted. And Every time a new object is created it has the number of clones that predeceased it. Im pretty new to C# some some help will be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class CreateEmpty : MonoBehaviour
{
Vector3 newPosition;
public GameObject[] Empty;
private bool spawnDelay = true;
public float EmptyAmount = 0f;
private float spawnDelayTime = 1.5f;

void Start()
{
    newPosition = transform.position;
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && spawnDelay)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            string EmptyAmountStr = EmptyAmount.ToString();
            newPosition = hit.point;
            transform.position = newPosition;
            GameObject empty = Instantiate(Empty[0], hit.point, Empty[0].transform.rotation); //create a game object called empty at the ray cast hitpoint

            empty.name = "empty" + EmptyAmountStr; //name the new empty to the amount of empties created
            EmptyAmount++;
            Debug.Log("Empty int amount: '" + EmptyAmount + "'" + " Empty str amount: '" + EmptyAmountStr + "'");

            GameObject go = GameObject.Find("empty" + EmptyAmount);
            if (go)
            {
                Destroy(go.gameObject);
                Debug.Log("empty has been destroyed");
            }
            spawnDelay = false;
            Invoke("DelayControl", spawnDelayTime);

        }
    }
}
void DelayControl()
{
    spawnDelay = true;
}
```

}

Comment: Just make your `empty` a class field and use it to destroy the object before assigning a new value to it

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple, you should make the "empty" variable a class member. Before every instantiation you should destroy the gameObject saved in "empty" and after that you can instantiate a new gameObject in this variable.

```
Destroy(empty);
empty = Instantiate(Empty[0], hit.point, Empty[0].transform.rotation);
empty.name = "empty" + EmptyAmount.ToString();
EmptyAmount++;
```

and EmptyAmount should probably be an unsigned integer, since you will never instantiate a half object (I think)

Comment: I have a question, when i do a variable++ nothing happens same with variable += 1.0f; any help?